# Access sharepoint list data in SQL

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint development.  I have a list, this list has a column that is called `Todaysdate`. This column needs to be updated daily to today's actual date and since it contains ~20,000 rows I am NOT going to update it manually everyday.  Because it's used in a calculation row.

My question is can I just use SQL and update the rows in the UserData table that correspond to the `datetime` column that I need?

I can query the list of rows by something similar to

```
Select * from UserData where tp_ListID = 'GUID'
```

but the data contained in the column `datetime3` is not just the `Todaysdate` information.  How do I return just the `Todaysdate` info?

Comment: just courious: why do you save todays date in a list??? theres a function i SharePoint (as far as I remember) that can give you todays date, so you don't need to save the information i a list?

Comment: Here is a [blog post](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dez/archive/2008/07/31/dynamically-updating-a-sharepoint-calculated-column-containing-a-quot-today-quot-reference.aspx) that can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not query let alone update the SharePoint content database directly using SQL. It is totally unsupported, so if you break something you are left alone, and the database schema may change with future service packs / releases.
Also as noesgard mentioned it in his comment you do not need it to use today's date in a calculated field, see [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/cjohnson/archive/2006/03/16/552314.aspx) on how you can do that.